# How to constrain class templates and data members with std::enable_if

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae, enable-if

I have a class template:

```cpp
template<int a, int b>
class foo {
};
```

I only want to instantiate it when `a + b == 10`.
Could I make this possible using `std::enable_if`?

Furthermore, if I have a data member in `class foo`:

```cpp
template<int a, int b>
class foo {
    int c;
};
```

I only want to have `c` when `a == 5`.

How do I do that using `std::enable_if`?
Is this one the correct case to use `std::enable_if`?

Comment: That's not what `enable_if` is for. It's only for *deduced* types in *function* templates.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Or to disable specializations of class templates. Both have been the core usages of `boost::enable_if` for a long time and both are still valid use cases. Note that this is usually done in the context of multiple specializations of a base template to select one over the others, rather than just disabling a template altogether.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: That's a good point. I've not used it for class template specializations a lot so far...

Comment: Simpler: `template<int a> class foo { static const int b = 10 - a;`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess you can use static_assert better to enforce that constraint instead of enable_if

```
template<int a, int b>
class foo {
    static_assert(a+b==10, "a+b is not 10");
};

int main()
{
    foo<5,5> f; // will compile
    foo<1,5> f; // will fail to compile with error: a+b is not 10
    return 0;
}
```

enable_if is primarily used to conditionally remove functions and classes from overload resolution based on type traits and to provide separate function overloads and specializations for different type traits.

Comment: I would choose this solution over a `std::enable_if` based one in order to spare the users of my library some severe headaches.

Comment: Yeah, I just want to learn how to use enable_if. But it might be the case that this is a very bad example :)

Answer (score 13):

```
template<int a, int b, typename T = typename std::enable_if<a + b == 10>::type>
class foo {
};
```

This should do the job; just make sure you never explicitly provide the third template parameter when instantiating the template.

---

As others mentioned, `static_assert` is a much better fit.

Comment: +1: While for just forcing a particular combination `static_assert` is better, this is more powerful as it allows to produce multiple specializations of a base template and select one or the other based on properties of the intantiating arguments

Comment: +1 for teaching me that you can use arithmetic and logic expressions in template arguments

Comment: OK, now I changed the requirement :-) What if I have a member \n

Comment: What if I have a member in class foo: int c and I only want to have that member when template parameter a is 5? How to do that using std::enable_if? @Zoidberg

Comment: @WhatABeautifulWorld You should specialise the template for 5. So you might have `template <int N>  struct foo { int a, b; }; template <> struct foo<5> { int a, b, c; };`

Answer (score 5):

### With C++20

You can achieve that simply by adding *`requires`* to the template:

```
template<int a, int b> requires (a + b == 10)
struct foo {
    int c;
};

int main() {
    foo<3, 7> ok;
    // foo<3, 8> doesnt_compile;
}
```

The *`requires`* clause gets a `constant expression` that evaluates to `true` or `false` deciding thus whether to consider this as a proper match, if the requires clause is true, or ignore it otherwise.

Code: https://godbolt.org/z/yHh4Et

Comment: what many fail to realise is one simple fact: static_assert does not constrain a type, it constrains an instnatiation.  One can compile a lot of  illegal types using `std` , e.g.  `using very_wrong = std::vector<void ***>` .  c++20 ad-hoc `requires` is very elegant and made with a reason.

Answer (score 3):

Simple, just don't use `enable_if`

```
template<bool Ten>
struct Base
{
    int c;
};

template<>
struct Base<false>
{ };

template<int a, int b>
struct foo : Base<a+b == 10>
{
};
```

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/Ez5rnGzvc