# std::enable_if second ask

Tags: c++, std, enable-if

I am quite new to std::enable_if and wondering how to use it.
I have a template class:

```
template<int a, int b>
class foo {
  int c;
}
```

I only want the template to have member c when

```
a = 5.
```

How do I do that using std::enable_if?
Is this one the correct case to use std::enable_if?

Comment: How is this different from your [first question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13260581/c-stdenable-if)? That is, why can't you use the technique suggested in the accepted answer there for this example as well?

Comment: The first one is about enforcing a+b follows some rules. THis one is about including c based on some rules about a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use partial specialization. No need of `std::enable_if`.

```
//primary template
template<int a, int b>
class foo 
{
      //whatever 
};

//partial specialization
template<int b>
class foo<5,b>  //when a = 5, this specialization will be used!
{
  int c;  //it has member c
};
```

Usage:

```
foo<1,3>  f1; //primary template is used
foo<5,3>  f2; //partial specialization is used
```

Comment: @WhatABeautifulWorld: Then ask the question properly. Give more information in the question. Also, you can try using base common class template if that helps.